# Using Inputbox for Filter Criteria in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter, criteria, inputbox

This may be lame but i need help in VBA while using Input Box for Filter Criteria. I'm trying to use below code where the user needs to put values in + & - to filter the range accordingly.

In this case i'm trying to filter 5 for upper range and -4.5 for lower range. The difficulty i am facing is that when i type -4.9, -4.8, -4.7 or -4.6 for lower range then the value is considered as -5 and when i use -4.5, -4.4, -4.3 and so on till -4.1 then the value is considered as -4. I need the value to be exact as i input in the input box.

```vb
Sub InputFilter()

    Dim iuval As Integer
    Dim ilval As Integer

    iuval = InputBox("Please enter the upper range")
    ilval = InputBox("Please enter the Lower range")


    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$71").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">" & iuval, _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<" & ilval

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the data type of `iuval` to `double` otherwise VBA will convert your input automatically to `integer` which means in your case it will convert your input to -4 or -5.

`Dim iuval As Integer`  should be `Dim iuval As double`

Do the same for `Dim ilval As Integer`.

Comment: And actually as ```InputBox``` returns a string and these values are then only concatenated , you could even define them as ```String```. The only point of using numeric datatypes here would be to ensure the user input a numeric value. But you have the ```IsNumeric``` function for this.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the better approach because we have a string comparision in `Criteria1:=">" & iuval` then which might give wrong results.  But you are right to be on the safe side on one should use `IsNumeric` before convertting.

Comment: Whatever is the type of ```iuval```, ```Criteria1``` will be a string (ie : ```">-4.5"```). Then it is the Excel engine that parses and interprets this string as a "greater than numeric value -4.5".

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) `criteria` is of datatype variant. But, of course, in this case it is a string and Excel will do the parsing.

Comment: Even if ```Criteria1``` can accept any datatype (that is the meaning of typing it as ```Variant```), ```">" & iuval``` returns a String as you concatenate a String (">") with anything else. So the value of the argument ```Criteria1``` in this context will always be a String

Comment: Greatfully appreciaate all your help. Using a string works as good as Double. Can i ask you you can provide isnumeric code that i can use here?